# How to parametrize type with variable? C++

Tags: c++

I have got templated class:

```
template<typename T, int L>
class SomeClass{...}
```

Then I would like user to specify the parameters when creating object, let's say by adding parameter when executing program in terminal for example `./a.out -i 20` for `SomeClass<int,20>` or `./a.out -d 20` for `SomeClass<double,20>`. How to do that?

Comment: You will have to enumerate all possible cases

Comment: you can not, template parameters must be set at compile time.

Comment: Why do you want this? You are absolutely suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for templates to be instantiable *at run time*; this is not possible with C++.

You can do one of the following:

1. Have a factory, and a limited number of fixed options, pre-instantiated, e.g.:

   ```
   std::BaseOfSomeClass* = SomeClassFactory.construct(argv[0], std::stoi(argv[1]));
   ```
2. Drop templates in favor of some kind of run-time polymorphism in SomeClass itself.
3. Switch to an interpreted/virtual-machine-based language, or a language with explicit JITing, in which you can do this.
4. Implement a runtime environment for C++ which supports JIT'ing...

Comment: You missed one case - invoke compiler and run produced executable :)

Answer (score 0):

Template parameters have different syntax from ordinary parameters to highlight they are *compile time* parameters. You can not specify them at runtime. You must use a normal parameter on the constructor of the class. Or enumerate all possible cases (including the integer parameter) like Slava pointed out.